# What is known about the statistical mechanics of systems with normally distributed energies?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

Consider a system taking on N states with energies $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Are such systems well-studied in any context?  I ask because I'd like to be able to take certain expectations related to the partition function.  For example, one can show that:

$<Z> = Ne^{\mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$

without too much trouble (in units where $\beta = 1$).  What I'd really like to be able to find, though, is $<\log Z>$.  To start, one could try Taylor-expanding $\log Z$ about $<Z>$, obtaining:

$<\log Z> \approx \log <Z> - \frac{1}{<Z>^2}Var(Z)$,

where:

$Var(Z) = Ne^{2\mu + 2\sigma^2} + N(N-1)e^{2\mu + \sigma^2} - <Z>^2.$

But my expression for $Var(Z)$ doesn't seem to agree very well with numerical simulations, perhaps because $Z$ itself is so right-skewed.  So, in sum, have such systems been studied before?  Thanks in advance-- statistical mechanics isn't quite my field.

Comment: It seems that there is, at least, a notation problem. $Z$ is a [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)#Definition), not a random variable. So, notations $<Z>$ or $<Log Z>$ or $Var(Z)$, make no sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm afraid I don't understand the objection: if the $\epsilon$'s are random variables, then $Z$ is a function of random variables and hence a random variable itself.  Clearly, for any given system the partition function is a constant, but think of it this way: saying that the energies are i.i.d. normal induces the multivariate normal distribution (with $\Sigma = I$) over all systems with N states.  If I draw a system at random from that distribution, what is $Z$ ($\log Z$, &c.) likely to be?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. The definition of the partition function is clear. If, for instance, we take a canonical ensemble description, we have $Z = \sum\limits_i e^{-\beta E_i}$. The probability to have the system in the energy $E_i$ is $p(E_i) = \frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta E_i}$. So, clearly, the energy is a random variable, but $Z$ is not a random variable. Adding independant variables do not change nothing, you have simply $Z = \Pi_{i=1}^n Z_i$, and  $Z$ and the $Z_i$ are not random variables.

Comment: I think we are talking at cross-purposes because I am approaching this problem in a slightly non-standard way.  If it helps, just forget about the statistical mechanical interpretation, and consider $E_i\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2), 1\leq i \leq N$ (i.i.d), and define $Z=\sum_i e^{-\beta E_i}$.  $Z$ is then a random variable.

Comment: This looks pretty much like the random energy model. See, for example, Chapter 9 in Anton Bovier's book *Statistical Mechanics of Disordered Systems: A Mathematical Perspective*.

Comment: @Trimok: This makes sense for a *disordered* model, such as the Edwards-Anderson model, the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick model, or the random energy (REM) model. In that case, the partition function is itself a random variable (depending on the realization of the disorder). What he asks for seems actually similar to the REM.

Comment: @wvoq: another place you can consult is Mezard+Montanari's book *Information, Physics and Computation", Chapter 5.

Comment: @YvanVelenik : Good point, so wiki [Spin glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_glass) seems to be  a good entry point for these models.